# Loop with 2 functions ran with '&' still runs them serially

Tags: linux, bash

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

done=
count=0

functionA { # MAIN
    sleep 30
    done=y
}

functionB() { #PROGRESS
    local A=${1:-30} #width
    local B=${2:-1} #count time 1s
    local C=${3:-"X"} #existing char
    local D=${4:-"*"} #override char
    local i

        echo -en "["
        for i in `seq 1 $A`
            do
                echo -en "$C"
        done

        echo -en "]\0015["
        for i in `seq 1 $A`
        do
            echo -en "$D"
                sleep ${B}
((counter++))
        done        
        echo
}
```

**functionA** is a placeholder for the main job of my script.

**functionB** is a blind progress indicator that has been chosen because it takes **functionA** an unpredictably different time to complete, and there are no way to measure the progress.

Thus, the idea was to probe every 10 s whether the **functionA** is still active (via the '*done*' marker), print the results of the probing, and whenever it finishes - stop **functionB** as well. Loop:

```
while [[ -z "$done" ]]; do
    if [ "$counter" -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "Started"
        else
            echo "Not yet finished..."
    fi
    functionB 10  &
    functionA $!
done
echo "Finished"
```

I expected these A and B functions to run independently, meaning **functionB** would keep running repeatedly in the loop of its subshell controlled by '*$done*' of **functionA**.

However, it runs only ones, and then just stops awaiting to **functionA** to finish the job, set the marker, and then quit.

If i run the progress function alone (*functionB 10*) it runs as expected - goes down to the next line after filling the 10 chars length bar, printing all the statuses. But not when both functions run with **&**.

What am i doing wrong? (please explain).

Comment: The first time you run `functionA` it sets `done=y`, so the `while` loop stops.

Comment: Background jobs don't share variables. All the variables are copied. After `functionA &` there are two processes with two `done` variables.

Comment: @Barmar - hmm...I thought it is set only after the sleep, so the function is done. How else I can alert the B that A is done?

Comment: There are several errors in your scripts. You're missing the parentheses in the definition of `functionA`. You set the variable `count`, but use `$counter` in the `if` statement.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having. When I fix those problems and run your script, it displays Started, shows the progress bar moving, and a little while later displays Finished and exits.

Comment: You're passing the PID of B to A, I assume it's supposed to do `kill $1` before it returns.

Comment: @Barmar - functionA doesn't have a parantnesses as it doesn't receive any external parameters. And my counter increments in the loop, so I had to declare it as 0 in global level

Comment: @Barmar - the sleep lasts 30 seconds, whereas the bar is of 10 seconds length. I expect it to show 3 10-chared  bars and then stop.

Comment: You can find some errors such as the ones noted above by pasting your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ .  For example, it flags the fact that `count=0` doesn't match later use of `$counter` ("count" vs "count`er`").

Comment: @faceless That doesn't matter, the syntax for a function is `<name> () <compound-command> [ <redirections> ]` or `function <name> [()] <compound-command> [ <redirections> ]`; `name <compound-command>` is incorrect.

Comment: @faceless You need a loop in `functionB` to make it repeat the progress bar from the beginning until it's killed. The main `while` loop doesn't repeat until `functionA` returns.

Comment: @Benjamin W. , Barmar - thank you guys, I will try to suit your comments to my script. cxw - I'll use your suggestion as scema for fixing my errors.   However, despite I am quite a new in bash, I've written many functions that doesn't have to have an external parameters without a (). Not my invention, but I learnt it from respectful sources, like: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html.   Is this still wrong?

Comment: The ABS is widely considered not a great source, actually. But in the page you're linking, every single function declaration uses `()` anyway. A good source is the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Barmar's comment - the thing that has to wait is the progress bar, so that's what should have the loop.  This works in my tests:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u
    # warn on use of undeclared variables

functionA() { # MAIN
    sleep 25     # So you can see it die in the middle of a functionB inner loop
}

functionB() { #PROGRESS
    local A=${1:-30} #width           # Please rename these to be, e.g., "width" :)
    local B=${2:-1} #count time 1s
    local C=${3:-"X"} #existing char
    local D=${4:-"*"} #override char
    local i

    while true            # Wait forever - the script will kill us when it's done
    do
        echo -en "["
        for i in $(seq 1 "$A")
        do
                echo -en "$C"
        done

        echo -en "]\0015["
        for i in $(seq 1 "$A")
        do
            echo -en "$D"
            sleep "${B}"
            # No need for a counter
        done
        echo
    done
}

functionB 10 &         # Start the progress bar - it will run until we say otherwise
progress_pid="$!"

functionA 

kill "$progress_pid"   # Stop the progress bar
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: your solution works well in this example. But 'set -u' makes troubles in my script meeting the very first "$1" variable (unbound variable), that are used in TUI. But w/o 'set -u' "$!" doesn't behave well. Is there any way to proceed without 'set -u'?

Comment: @faceless Sure, just remove `set -u`.  I'm not sure what "TUI" is, but you may not want to ignore the error in TUI - the error message may be pointing you to a subtle bug.  Re. `$!`, it works for me with or without `set -u`.  If you have problems, try to [make the smallest test script you can](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows `$!` working with `set -u` and failing without `set -u`, and then ask that as another question.  Good luck!